# Which is the best way to link Widgets between .kv and .py file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I need some help in order to understand Kivy library.
If i have to create a questionary like this example :[image]

But with a button in order to change page that will stay in the same position how I have to proceed?
How I link lots of widgets together and the .kv file with the .py file?
I'm trying but without any results.

For exemple i've written this code with a button and a colored background but it doesn't work :

.py Part :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Principale(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('questionario.kv')
        Principale()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

.kv Part:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<Principale>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb : 0.2549,0.73333,0.12156
        Rectangle:
            size:self.size
    size_hint : 1,1
    orientation:"vertical"
    padding : 30

    Button:
        text: "ciao"
        size_hint : 0.12,0.12
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: In the `build` method you must return the instance of your root widget: `return Principale()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('questionario.kv')
        Principale()
```

You need to return Principale here.

```
return Principale()
```

Not just create it.

Also, you called your App TryApp but you're trying to run something called PongApp

So this:

```
PongApp().run()
```

Should be:

```
TryApp().run()
```

So it should look like this in the end:

```
class TryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('questionario.kv')
        return Principale()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TryApp().run()
```

Note: It is harmless but you don't need to declare the kv as root. It already knows in this case.